# Find SQL Server edition and version from setup files without installing

Tags: sql-server, installation

I want to know how to find SQL Server edition and version details from SQL Server setup without installing it. I have been in situations where sysadmins put SQL Server setup files on a file server without proper file names. So it confuses me a lot of time of which version and edition the setup file is.

I tried to find txt/word files having those details in setup but didn't get any. Please let me know if it is possible to find that out.

I am looking for details like SQL Server 2005/2008/2012 X64/X86 STD/ENT/DEV Edition.

The related question [Determine the SQL Server version and edition from the available set up, before actually installing it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98146/how-can-we-determine-the-sql-server-version-and-edition-from-the-available-set-u) does give me version details (like 10, 10.50, 11, etc.); however, how to find the edition? It doesn't give that.